# How to know if an insertion was successfull in a MongoDB Collection with Meteor.JS (inside the Template)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, meteor

### **The situation**

Let's break this question down to a simple todo list of which the entries are listed in a \li:

```
//main.html
<ul>
{{ #each listEntries }}
  <li class="item">
   {{ title }}
  </li>
{{ /each }}
</ul>
```

Serverside:

```
//main.js
TodoCollection = new Mongo.Collection('todo_collection');
```

Now I am calling manually from the console in the client:

```
TodoCollection.insert({title: 'My first entry'});
```

### **Up to this point everything's fine**.

Now meteor.JS works asynchronously which means that the changes that are made in the client also have effect on the DOM right away without knowing if the database insertion was successfull or not. If not, the DOM Element will be removed again (so first meteor inserts the new `<li>`, then it removes it again if insertion failed).

How can you get the information from meteor that something comes actually from the database?

### What I need:

```
//main.html
<ul>
{{ #each listEntries }}
  <li class="item">
   {{ title }}

   {{ #if isInDatabase }}
     - i am actually stored!
   {{ /if }}
  </li>
{{ /each }}
</ul>
```

Comment: You can do the insertion in a method stub, such that you insert it with a flag which indicates that the data is temporary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the most trivial solution myself:
Adding a hook on server-side that will add the date of creation with `obj.onCreated = new Date();` helps identifying that it came from the server because this will not exist on the client.

```
  {{#each item}}
    {{ #if item.onCreated }}
      <li class="success-db">{{name}}</li>
    {{ else }}
      <li class="pending-db">{{name}}</li>
    {{ /if }}
  {{/each}}
```

(Please do not hesitate to improve this answer if you find it contradictory to how Meteor.JS works)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the callback of the insert method of the collection. The callback is called with the error (`null` if there is none) and the object Id that was stored in the database

Below you can see the code to test this:

**html**:

```
<head>
  <title>simple</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Welcome to Meteor!</h1>
  {{>test}}
</body>

<template name="test">
  <ul>
      {{#each item in list}}
      <li>{{item.name}}</li>
      {{/each}}
  </ul>
  {{#if insertResult}}
  <div class="insert_result">{{insertResult}}</div>
  {{/if}}
  {{#if insertError}}
  <div class="insert_error">{{insertError}}</div>
  {{/if}}
  <form>
      <input type="text" name="name" />
      <input type="submit" value="Add" />
  </form>
</template>
```

**Javascript**:

```
import { Template } from 'meteor/templating';
import { ReactiveVar } from 'meteor/reactive-var';

collection = new Mongo.Collection('collection');

if (Meteor.isClient) {
    Template.test.onCreated(function () {
        this.insertResult = new ReactiveVar();
        this.insertError = new ReactiveVar();
    });

    Template.test.helpers({
        list() {
            return collection.find();
        },
        insertResult() {
            return Template.instance().insertResult.get();
        },
    });

    Template.test.events({
        'submit form'(event, instance) {
            event.preventDefault();
            collection.insert({
                name: event.target.name.value
            },function(err,result) {
                if (err) {
                    instance.insertError.set(err);
                    instance.insertResult.set(null);
                } else {
                    instance.insertResult.set(result);
                    instance.insertError.set(null);
                }

            });
        },
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this proposed solution. In your example though it does not take place inside the corresponding `<li>` but more globally outside the `<ul>`.
It shows what you can do with meteor but it does not solve the reference problem: I do not know which `<li>` was added by Meteor (I could use something like :last-child but that would not ensure that this is the element I am looking for because it could also be another one that has been added in the meantime).

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the previous answer, it is quite cumbersome in Meteor to know what causes a reactive update.

I would suggest a different approach: Don't insert on the client. Make a `Meteor.call()` to a server method which does the insert, and then let the client update reactively. Then you are **always** sure that what you see on the screen is actually in the database.

Comment: That is not a proper solution for me. Let me explain: 
I want to have that "extra special" of meteor adding the DOMElement in the client. But I want (for UX reasons) to show the User that the Element is currently being added -> idle mode. 
Your solution would work but it would make things really unnecessarily complicated.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to show the data which title exist then you can write the code like this.

```
<ul>
{{ #each listEntries }}
  <li class="item">
   {{ title }}

   {{ #if title }}
     - i am actually stored!
   {{ /if }}
  </li>
{{ /each }}
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi Pankaj. Have you read the question? How would your proposed solution help solving the issue?

Comment: I hope you are aware to minimongo concept of meteor. So when you client minmongo sync with server mongo database. The function also insert a predictable result on client mongo, In case operation permitted then by the server, client mongo get back to old state.

Comment: listEntries helper must be restrung date like : TodoCollection.find();

Comment: Hi Pankaj. I am sorry that you misunderstood my question. I fully understand the concept which is good and desired. But I wanted to enhance the User Experience by showing that an entry was statically inserted to the DB because there are cases when this is important for the user to be aware of (critical data was inserted, e.g. mail that is important). I know that it will get back to the old state when the operation was not successful but this is really not helpful at the moment but thanks.